# Can't seem to insert into my database

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add a genre of music our venue performs to our database. The table consists on a genre name and an a simple private key. for whatever reason when I run this code I get an error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Musical_Styles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO Musical_Styles (StyleID, StyleName)
VALUES ('26', 'AltROCK')
```

Comment: Set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`?

Comment: How do I do that? I've never had this happen before

Comment: Why you use quote `'26'` if the comumn is an `INT` datatype?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, your column `StyleID` is defined as `INT IDENTITY` - this means, SQL Server will automagically auto-increment that column for every insert - and it means **you** shouldn't provide values for it explicitly - just let SQL Server handle it!

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Musical_Styles (StyleName)
VALUES ('AltROCK')
```

But if you **really** must provide an explicit value - for whatever reasons - then you must first enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the table, insert your values, and turn off identity insert again:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Musical_Styles ON;

INSERT INTO Musical_Styles (StyleID, StyleName)
VALUES (26, 'AltROCK');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Musical_Styles OFF;
```

and since `StyleID` most likely is an `INT` column, do **not** put the value into single quotes (that makes it a string, and causes unnecessary back and forth conversions).

Answer (score 1):

That will do the job:

```
USE YourDB
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema.YourTable ON;

INSERT INTO Musical_Styles
(StyleID, StyleName)
VALUES (26, 'AltROCK');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema.YourTable OFF;
```

Comment: And you should **always** turn **OFF** identity insert again right after you're done ....